# React - Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There are many instances of this error on Stack Overflow but sadly nothing that has aided in debugging the issue. Hoping someone can help me to understand why, see below my code.

**Navbar.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
 const Navbar = ()=>{
    return(
            <nav className="nav-wrapper">
                <div className="container">
                    <Link to="/" className="brand-logo">Shopping</Link>

                    <ul className="right">
                        <li><Link to="/">Shop</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/cart">My cart</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/cart"><i className="material-icons">shopping_cart</i></Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>  
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './assets/logo.png';
import './styles/App.css';
import CartHeader from './components/CartHeader.js';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="App-header-left">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="App-header-right">
          <CartHeader />
        </div>
      </header>

      <body className="App-body">
        <div className="App-body-image-container">
          <h1 className="Green-header">Greenleaf</h1><h2 className="White-header">The apple of your eye.</h2>
        </div>
      </body>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**package.json:**
Amongst many other things, `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"`, is listed under dependencies.

The app itself compiles without errors, but the *Error: Invariant failed: You should not use < Link > outside a < Router >* error is shown in the browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

so I can see you're using `<Link>` and importing it from the right place, however, you're not wrapping your `<App>` in a `<Router>`.

Check out the [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) documentation for extra support.

Here's an example of how `react-router-dom` works:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If you notice, the Links are inside the Router.

So in your case, you might want to do:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './assets/logo.png';
import './styles/App.css';
import CartHeader from './components/CartHeader.js';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.js';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="App-header-left">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="App-header-right">
          <CartHeader />
        </div>
      </header>

      <body className="App-body">
        <div className="App-body-image-container">
          <h1 className="Green-header">Greenleaf</h1><h2 className="White-header">The apple of your eye.</h2>
        </div>
      </body>

    </div>
    <Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried to wrap the <App/> tag in index.js in <Router /> but it threw an undefined error, adding it inside the app tags in App.js seems to have fixed things! Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks so much; I forget to use <Router>  </Router> in App.js tag after I use Link tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrap your App component with Router tag?
as example:

```
// index.js

<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

also resource from its docs https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: I get the following `Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
  Line 9:6:  'Router' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.` if I wrap the `<App />` tag in a `<Router />` tag. Do I need to reference react-router-dom in index.js?

Comment: yea, you should `import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'` in your `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is right inside official doc from reactstrap for Navbar https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

They guided that we need to use this import

```
import {NavLink} from 'reactstrap';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong import.

Change this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

to this:

```
import Link from "next/link";
```